# Google Maps API - How to add content to one Infowindow for one marker while reserving existing content from array?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to fetch information from an JavaScript array which includes a Campaign name and its relevant Country. I have added a marker to each country and I want the infowindow at each marker location to display all the Campaigns relevant to that country. For example, Argentina has contributed to Campaign 1, Campaign 3, and Campaign 4. The infowindow should display these 3 campaigns. Keep in mind that each array element consists of 1 Campaign and 1 Country. It sounds simple to do but after days of research I couldn't find how to do it.

Below you can find the HTML code as it is. I don't know how to upload the JSON file and link it to the HTML file on Stackoverflow, so I copied it into JavaScript, sorry for the inconvenience. The code snippet won't run correctly because of that.

```js
data = '[' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 5", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"}, ' +
  '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"} ' +
  ']';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JSONTEST.json"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lausanne = new google.maps.LatLng(46.515237, 6.610980);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      //size: new google.maps.Size(150,150)
      maxWidth: 500,
    });


    var markers = [];

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
          center: lausanne,
          zoom: 3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        var campaigns = JSON.parse(data); //Loads the data in JSONTEST.json


        for (var i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
          var found = false;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(campaigns[i].Latitude, campaigns[i].Longitude);
          for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
            if (markers[j].Campaign == campaigns[i].Campaign && markers[j].Country == campaigns[i].Country) {
              markers[j].Count++;
              found = true;
              break;
            }

          }
          if (found == false) {
            var marker = {
              Campaign: campaigns[i].Campaign,
              Country: campaigns[i].Country,
              Count: 1,
              Lat: campaigns[i].Latitude,
              Long: campaigns[i].Longitude
            }
            markers.push(marker);
          }
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          createMarker(markers[i]);
        }


      } //end of function initialize


    function createMarker(marker) {

      var contentString = '<div class="map-content"><h2>' + marker.Campaign + '</h2><h3>Number of ideas submitted from ' + marker.Country + ' : ' + marker.Count + ' </h3></div>';

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (marker.Country == markers[i].Country) {



        }
      }

      // var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(markers.Lat, markers.Long);
      var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.Lat, marker.Long),
        map: map,
        //zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        icon: 'circle.png'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, Marker);
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:900px;"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?  [The posted code seems to work for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6eqfpoen/1/).  Do you want to know how to display details about the 3 campaigns in Argentina in its infowindow (for example)?

Comment: Yes exactly. The code works but I don't know how to display the three campaigns from Argentina in the Argentina Markers Infowindow.

Answer (score 0):

I brush up your code a little.

**update: open multiple infowindows**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var data = '[' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 2", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "Argentina", "Latitude": "-34.61315", "Longitude": "-58.37723"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 5", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"}, ' +
    '{"Campaign": "Campaign 1", "Country": "USA", "Latitude": "40.71427", "Longitude": "-74.00597"} ' +
    ']';

    var lausanne = new google.maps.LatLng(46.515237, 6.610980);



    var markers = [];

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
          center: lausanne,
          zoom: 3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        var campaigns = JSON.parse(data); //Loads the data in JSONTEST.json

        // Reduce campaigns
        var campaignDics = campaigns.reduce(function(dictionary, data) {
          var country = data.Country;
          var campaign = data.Campaign;
          dictionary[country] = dictionary[country] || {};
          dictionary[country][campaign] = dictionary[country][campaign] || {};
          if (!dictionary[country][campaign].Count) {
            dictionary[country][campaign] = {
              Campaign: campaign,
              Country: country,
              Count: 1,
              Lat: data.Latitude,
              Long: data.Longitude
            };
          } else {
            dictionary[country][campaign].Count++;
          }

          return dictionary;
        }, {});

        // Create markers
        for (var country in campaignDics) {
          for (var campaign in campaignDics[country]) {
            console.log(country + " - " + campaign);
            markers.push(createMarker(campaignDics[country][campaign]));
          }
        }

      } //end of function initialize


    function createMarker(params) {
      // [update here] Create a infoWindow inside this function.
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //size: new google.maps.Size(150,150)
        maxWidth: 500,
      });
      var contentString = '<div class="map-content"><h2>' + params.Campaign + '</h2><h3>Number of ideas submitted from ' + params.Country + ' : ' + params.Count + ' </h3></div>';

      // var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(markers.Lat, markers.Long);
      var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(params.Lat, params.Long),
        map: map//,
        //zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        //icon: 'circle.png'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, Marker);
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:900px;"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping out and brushing the code. Looks much more nicer. It's just that I need to display all the campaigns from 1 country in 1 infowindow, for example Argentina has Campaign 1 and Campaign 2 and I need to display both campaigns on the same infowindow. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: If you want to open multiple infoWindows, create infoWindow in the createMarker() function.

Comment: Well I don't need to open multiple infowindows but what I need is to open multiple array elements in a single infowindow. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself?